# How to select a checkbox from multiple check boxes having same class,type,value and tab index And checkbox id keeps on changing

Tags: javascript, testing, xpath, automation

There are multiple check boxes in a web page. I need to select single check box. But all the check boxes have the same type,value,tab index. only the checkbox id is different but the id is getting generated dynamically for every execution and my test script is getting failed.

How can I write the xpath to select a single check box?

Comment: do you want to select any single checkbox ? or it has to be a specific one ? can you share a sample html ? also share what xpath you have tried.

Comment: You need to figured out what is the invariant.

Comment: This the html : <span class="CheckBox"><input type="checkbox" value="on" id="uid-1281" tabindex="0"><label for="uid-1281"></label></span>
<span class="CheckBox"><input type="checkbox" value="on" id="uid-1285" tabindex="0"><label for="uid-1285"></label></span>

Comment: The only thing thats varying is the id. But this id is changing every time the screen is opened

Comment: Do you want to select 1st checkbox all the times? Are these checkboxes have associatd values?

Answer (score 0):

Gere `checkbox1` is the name of your checkbox:

```
$('input[name="checkbox1[]"]').on('click', function(){
  console.log("hi")
});
```